# Will layout folders fix the tablet compatibility?

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet

I read a few things about how to make your app compatible with tablets. Some say about using your code and some say about the layout folders or some about the sw600dp and sw720dp folders. I am really confused and am not 100% sure which is the most simplest way to just make it play on a tablet.

What i did is i made 3 more layout folders (large, xlarge and small, I already had the drawable classes in all sizes but i didnt change the size of the images, its in all drawables the same size) and in these 3 extra folders i copied the same files i had in the plain layout folder. So i have 4 layouts with all the xmls the same.

Will this make it compatible with tablet and fix my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Xlarge use this folder drawable-xlarge-hdpi

for large use this folder drawable-large-xhdpi

layout-large (7 inch)

layout-xlarge(10 inch) folder are used for layouts

Comment: i have both drawable xlarge and layout xlarge. So i quess am ok right?:P

Comment: for 10 inch i suggest drawable-xlarge-hdpi not drawable-xlarge

Comment: whats the difference?

Comment: Hello again m8.I made all the folders etc but my application says again that its not compatible with tablets in the play store

Comment: which  folders have you used?

Comment: layout, layout-small, layout-large, layout-xlarge

Comment: yes those 2. Oh now that i look at it, i only have in drawable-ldpi my icons. In the other drawables i dont have all me images. That could be tha problem?

Comment: make above mentioned drawable folders in your app and put all the images into them

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way to make your app adopt to different hardware configurations is using folders. The framework will do all the work for you. ([tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidResourceSelection/article.html))